# What is the term for median but use the geometric mean instead of arithmetic mean if there are an even number of values?

Tags: median

"Geometric median" seems like the obvious choice for "median (but for even number of values, take the geometric mean of the central two values instead of the arithmetic mean)", but this seems to have a different meaning. Is there a term for this type of median?